# Unable to ping to a host

Tags: ssh, tcp, ping, icmp

I'm able to ssh to a host from my machine but when I try to ping the host from my machine, it says 100% packet loss !!

So my query is that what all could be the possible reasons behind this behavior (able to SSH but unable to PING through the same machine).

NOTE: All communication were tried using IP address of the target host.

Comment: Do you use IP-addresses or host names?

Answer (score 0):

Two common reasons:

1. Firewall. in local host, target host, or somewhere in route between hosts.
2. ICMP echo responsing is disabled in the target host.
3. If DNS query is used, ping and ssh tools may select different IP from the response. For example ping may select IPv6 address, and ssh IPv4 address. --> Try tools with IP addresses instead of host names.

Comment: I tried to put this reason as justification for the above mentioned behavior (SSH is working while PING isn't).....So I don't think reason 1 (firewall stuff) can be an issue.
Coming to 2nd reason.... need to check the target host... if ICMP echo responsing is disabled !!

Comment: Firewalls can be configured very creatively: ICMP-echo-request, TCP-ports etc can be configured separately.